# combinatorial identity involving fraction and product of bionomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

How can I prove the following identity for $i\geq 1$:

$$
\sum_{t=i}^{s-1} \frac{i}{t}\binom{2(s-t-1)}{s-t-1}\binom{2t-i-1}{t-1}= \binom{2s-i-2}{s-1}.
$$

Perhaps I'll need to go to hypergeometric functions?

Comment: If $i=0$ then LHS$=0$ and RHS$\neq0$, so something must be wrong.

Comment: Does the question give some more information, or just this supposed identity ?

Comment: @drhab Okay, $i\geq 1$.

Comment: Er, it is related to the coefficient of series expansion of $((a+b)+\sqrt{(a-b)^2+4abx})/2)^p$ in $x$. Perhaps one can treat it just like an identity for now...?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we seek to verify that

$$\sum_{k=q}^{n-1}
\frac{q}{k} {2n-2k-2\choose n-k-1} {2k-q-1\choose k-1}
= {2n-q-2\choose n-1}.$$

This is the same as

$$\sum_{k=q}^n
\frac{q}{k} {2n-2k\choose n-k} {2k-q-1\choose k-1}
= {2n-q\choose n}.$$

which is equivalent to

$$\sum_{k=q}^n
\frac{q-k}{k} {2n-2k\choose n-k} {2k-q-1\choose k-1}
+ \sum_{k=q}^n
{2n-2k\choose n-k} {2k-q-1\choose k-1}
\\ = {2n-q\choose n}.$$

Now
$$\frac{q-k}{k} {2k-q-1\choose k-1}
= \frac{q-k}{k} \frac{(2k-q-1)!}{(k-1)! (k-q)!}
\\ = - \frac{(2k-q-1)!}{k! (k-q-1)!}
= - {2k-q-1\choose k}.$$

It follows that what we have is in fact

$$\sum_{k=q}^n
{2n-2k\choose n-k} 
\left( {2k-q-1\choose k-1} - {2k-q-1\choose k} \right)
= {2n-q\choose n}$$

or alternatively

$$\sum_{k=q}^n
{2n-2k\choose n-k} 
\left( {2k-q-1\choose k-q} - {2k-q-1\choose k-q-1} \right)
= {2n-q\choose n}.$$

There are two pieces here, call them $A$ and $B$.

We use the integral representation

$${2n-2k\choose n-k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2n-2k}}{z^{n-k+1}} \; dz$$

which is  zero when $k\gt  n$ (pole vanishes)  so we may extend  $k$ to
infinity.

We also use the integral

$${2k-q-1\choose k-q}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{2k-q-1}}{w^{k-q+1}} \; dw$$

which is zero when $k\lt q$ so we may extend $k$ back to zero.

We obtain for piece $A$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{w^{q-1}}{(1+w)^{q+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^{n+1}} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{z^k}{(1+z)^{2k}}
\frac{(1+w)^{2k}}{w^k}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{w^{q-1}}{(1+w)^{q+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-z(1+w)^2/w/(1+z)^2}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{w^{q}}{(1+w)^{q+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2n+2}}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{w(1+z)^2-z(1+w)^2}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{w^{q-1}}{(1+w)^{q+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2n+2}}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{(z-w)(z-1/w)}
\; dz \; dw.$$

The derivation for piece $B$ is the same and yields

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{w^{q}}{(1+w)^{q+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2n+2}}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{(z-w)(z-1/w)}
\; dz \; dw.$$

The difference of these two is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{w^{q-1}}{(1+w)^{q+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2n+2}}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1-w}{(z-w)(z-1/w)}
\; dz \; dw.$$

Using partial fractions by residues we get

$$\frac{1-w}{(z-w)(z-1/w)}
= \frac{1-w}{w-1/w} \frac{1}{z-w}
+ \frac{1-w}{1/w-w} \frac{1}{z-1/w}
\\ = \frac{w(1-w)}{w^2-1} \frac{1}{z-w}
+ \frac{w(1-w)}{1-w^2} \frac{1}{z-1/w}
= - \frac{w}{1+w} \frac{1}{z-w}
+ \frac{w}{1+w} \frac{1}{z-1/w}
\\ = \frac{1}{1+w} \frac{1}{1-z/w}
- \frac{w^2}{1+w} \frac{1}{1-wz}.$$

At this point  we can see that there will be  no contribution from the
second term but  this needs to be verified. We get  for the residue in
$z$

$$- \frac{w^2}{1+w} 
\sum_{p=0}^n {2n+2\choose p} w^{n-p}$$

There is no  pole at zero in the outer integral  for a contribution of
zero.

Continuing with the first term we get

$$\frac{1}{1+w} 
\sum_{p=0}^n {2n+2\choose p} \frac{1}{w^{n-p}}$$

which yields

$$\sum_{p=0}^n {2n+2\choose p}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{w^{q-1}}{(1+w)^{q+2}}
\frac{1}{w^{n-p}} \; dw
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^n {2n+2\choose p}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{q+2}}
\frac{1}{w^{n-q-p+1}} \; dw
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^n {2n+2\choose p}
(-1)^{n-q-p} {n-p+1\choose q+1}.$$

This is

$$\sum_{p=0}^n {2n+2\choose p}
(-1)^{n-q-p} {n-p+1\choose n-p-q}.$$

The last integral we will be using is

$${n-p+1\choose n-p-q}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+v)^{n-p+1}}{v^{n-p-q+1}} \; dv.$$

Observe  that this  is zero  when $p\ge  n$ so  we may  extend  $p$ to
infinity, getting

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+v)^{n+1}}{v^{n-q+1}} 
\sum_{p\ge 0} {2n+2\choose p} (-1)^{n-q-p} 
\frac{v^p}{(1+v)^{p}}
\; dv
\\ = (-1)^{n-q}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+v)^{n+1}}{v^{n-q+1}} 
\left(1-\frac{v}{1+v}\right)^{2n+2}
\; dv
\\ = (-1)^{n-q}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|v|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{v^{n-q+1}} \frac{1}{(1+v)^{n+1}}
\; dv
\\= (-1)^{n-q} (-1)^{n-q} {n-q+n\choose n}
= {2n-q\choose n}.$$

This is the claim. QED.

Comment: Um, this seems to have a bit of flavour of inversion Lagrange's formula